# Installed beignet to use OpenCL on Intel, but OpenCL programs only work when run as root

Tags: python, opencl, gpu, intel, gpgpu

I have an Intel HD graphics 4000 3rd Gen Processor, and my OS is Linux Mint 17.1 64 bit. I installed `beignet` to be able to use `OpenCL` and thus run programs on the GPU. I had been having lots of problems using the `pyOpenCL` bindings, so I just decided to uninstall my current `beignet` version and install the latest one (You can see the previous question I asked and answered myself about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900363/pyopencl-returns-errors-the-first-run-then-only-invalid-program-errors-examp)).

Upgrading `beignet` worked and I can now run `OpenCL` code on my GPU through `python` and `C/C++` bindings. However, I can only run the programs as root, otherwise they don't detect my GPU as a valid device.

The programs *work*, which is great, but now I'm trying to solve the annoyance of having to run everything as root.

When I don't run them as root, I get the following error:

```
/dev/dri/card0 not authenticated
Device open failed, aborting...
/dev/dri/card0 not authenticated
Device open failed, aborting...
cl_get_gt_device(): error, unknown device: ffffffff
```

When I run them as root, they *work*, but first they show the following message:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia not found.
```

I tried `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` but for some reason that also uninstalled `pyOpenCL` and of course my python programs stopped working. I also found an answer here suggesting to check the permissions of the `/dev/nvidia*/` folder, but it doesn't exist in my computer.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** adding some requested outputs.

Output from `lspci | grep -i vga`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

Output from `glxinfo`:

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, 
    GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, 
    GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_swap_control

client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, 
    GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, 
    GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, 
    GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync

GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, 
    GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync

OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile 
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.1.3
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
    GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1, GL_AMD_conservative_depth, 
    GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend, GL_AMD_performance_monitor, 
    GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture, GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax, 
    GL_AMD_vertex_shader_layer, GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3, 
    GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5, GL_APPLE_object_purgeable, 
    GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility, GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility, GL_ARB_base_instance, 
    GL_ARB_blend_func_extended, GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_conservative_depth, GL_ARB_copy_buffer, GL_ARB_debug_output, 
    GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float, GL_ARB_depth_clamp, GL_ARB_draw_buffers, 
    GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend, GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex, 
    GL_ARB_draw_indirect, GL_ARB_draw_instanced, 
    GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location, GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_shader, GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_ARB_get_program_binary, 
    GL_ARB_half_float_pixel, GL_ARB_half_float_vertex, 
    GL_ARB_instanced_arrays, GL_ARB_internalformat_query, 
    GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata, GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment, 
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect, 
    GL_ARB_occlusion_query2, GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object, GL_ARB_point_sprite, 
    GL_ARB_provoking_vertex, GL_ARB_robustness, GL_ARB_sample_shading, 
    GL_ARB_sampler_objects, GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map, 
    GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counters, GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding, 
    GL_ARB_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod, 
    GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack, GL_ARB_shading_language_packing, 
    GL_ARB_sync, GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object_rgb32, GL_ARB_texture_buffer_range, 
    GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc, GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array, 
    GL_ARB_texture_float, GL_ARB_texture_gather, 
    GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge, GL_ARB_texture_multisample, 
    GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, GL_ARB_texture_query_levels, 
    GL_ARB_texture_query_lod, GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, GL_ARB_texture_rg, 
    GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui, GL_ARB_texture_storage, 
    GL_ARB_texture_storage_multisample, GL_ARB_texture_swizzle, 
    GL_ARB_timer_query, GL_ARB_transform_feedback2, 
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback3, GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced, 
    GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object, GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_object, GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_shader, GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev, GL_ARB_viewport_array, 
    GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate, GL_ATI_texture_float, GL_EXT_abgr, 
    GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, GL_EXT_draw_buffers2, 
    GL_EXT_draw_instanced, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil, GL_EXT_packed_float, 
    GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object, GL_EXT_provoking_vertex, 
    GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix, GL_EXT_texture_array, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1, GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc, 
    GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_EXT_texture_integer, 
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode, 
    GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent, GL_EXT_texture_snorm, 
    GL_EXT_texture_swizzle, GL_EXT_timer_query, GL_EXT_transform_feedback, 
    GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra, GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays, GL_KHR_debug, 
    GL_MESA_pack_invert, GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba, 
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp, GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil, 
    GL_OES_EGL_image, GL_OES_read_format, GL_S3_s3tc

OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.1.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1, GL_AMD_conservative_depth, 
    GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend, GL_AMD_performance_monitor, 
    GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture, GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax, 
    GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3, GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5, 
    GL_APPLE_object_purgeable, GL_APPLE_packed_pixels, 
    GL_APPLE_vertex_array_object, GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility, 
    GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility, GL_ARB_blend_func_extended, 
    GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object, GL_ARB_color_buffer_float, 
    GL_ARB_conservative_depth, GL_ARB_copy_buffer, GL_ARB_debug_output, 
    GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float, GL_ARB_depth_clamp, GL_ARB_depth_texture, 
    GL_ARB_draw_buffers, GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend, 
    GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex, GL_ARB_draw_instanced, 
    GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location, GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_program, GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_shader, GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_ARB_get_program_binary, 
    GL_ARB_half_float_pixel, GL_ARB_half_float_vertex, 
    GL_ARB_instanced_arrays, GL_ARB_internalformat_query, 
    GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata, GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment, 
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_multisample, GL_ARB_multitexture, 
    GL_ARB_occlusion_query, GL_ARB_occlusion_query2, 
    GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object, GL_ARB_point_parameters, GL_ARB_point_sprite, 
    GL_ARB_provoking_vertex, GL_ARB_robustness, GL_ARB_sample_shading, 
    GL_ARB_sampler_objects, GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map, 
    GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counters, GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding, 
    GL_ARB_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod, 
    GL_ARB_shading_language_100, GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack, 
    GL_ARB_shading_language_packing, GL_ARB_shadow, GL_ARB_sync, 
    GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp, GL_ARB_texture_compression, 
    GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc, GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, 
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array, GL_ARB_texture_env_add, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_combine, GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3, GL_ARB_texture_float, GL_ARB_texture_gather, 
    GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge, GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat, 
    GL_ARB_texture_multisample, GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, 
    GL_ARB_texture_query_levels, GL_ARB_texture_query_lod, 
    GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, GL_ARB_texture_rg, GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui, 
    GL_ARB_texture_storage, GL_ARB_texture_storage_multisample, 
    GL_ARB_texture_swizzle, GL_ARB_timer_query, GL_ARB_transform_feedback2, 
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback3, GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced, 
    GL_ARB_transpose_matrix, GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra, GL_ARB_vertex_array_object, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding, GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_program, GL_ARB_vertex_shader, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev, GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev, 
    GL_ARB_window_pos, GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate, GL_ATI_draw_buffers, 
    GL_ATI_envmap_bumpmap, GL_ATI_separate_stencil, 
    GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3, GL_ATI_texture_float, GL_EXT_abgr, 
    GL_EXT_bgra, GL_EXT_blend_color, GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, 
    GL_EXT_blend_func_separate, GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract, 
    GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array, GL_EXT_copy_texture, GL_EXT_draw_buffers2, 
    GL_EXT_draw_instanced, GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, GL_EXT_fog_coord, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled, GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters, 
    GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil, 
    GL_EXT_packed_float, GL_EXT_packed_pixels, GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object, 
    GL_EXT_point_parameters, GL_EXT_polygon_offset, GL_EXT_provoking_vertex, 
    GL_EXT_rescale_normal, GL_EXT_secondary_color, 
    GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects, GL_EXT_separate_specular_color, 
    GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix, GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, GL_EXT_stencil_two_side, 
    GL_EXT_stencil_wrap, GL_EXT_subtexture, GL_EXT_texture, GL_EXT_texture3D, 
    GL_EXT_texture_array, GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc, GL_EXT_texture_cube_map, 
    GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_env_add, 
    GL_EXT_texture_env_combine, GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3, 
    GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_EXT_texture_integer, 
    GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias, GL_EXT_texture_object, GL_EXT_texture_rectangle, 
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode, 
    GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent, GL_EXT_texture_snorm, 
    GL_EXT_texture_swizzle, GL_EXT_timer_query, GL_EXT_transform_feedback, 
    GL_EXT_vertex_array, GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra, 
    GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays, GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip, 
    GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_INGR_blend_func_separate, GL_KHR_debug, 
    GL_MESA_pack_invert, GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba, GL_MESA_window_pos, 
    GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp, 
    GL_NV_light_max_exponent, GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil, 
    GL_NV_primitive_restart, GL_NV_texgen_reflection, 
    GL_NV_texture_env_combine4, GL_NV_texture_rectangle, GL_OES_EGL_image, 
    GL_OES_read_format, GL_S3_s3tc, GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp, GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_lod, GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays

20 GLX Visuals
visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x020 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x021 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x08b 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x08c 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x08d 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x08e 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x08f 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x090 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x091 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x092 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x093 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x094 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x095 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x096 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x097 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x098 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x099 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x09a 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x09b 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x05e 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None

44 GLXFBConfigs:
visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x05f  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x060  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x061  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x062  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x063  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x064  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x065 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x066 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x067 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x068 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x069  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06a  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x06b 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06c 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x06d  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x06e  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x06f  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x070  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x071 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x072 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x073 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x074 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x075  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x076  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x077  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x078  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x079  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07a  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07b 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07c 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07d 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07e 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07f  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x080  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x081 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x082 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x083  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x084  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x085  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x086  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x087 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x088 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x089 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x08a 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I'm having a similar problem.

Comment: @silgon no, I'm still only able to run the programs as root and get errors when I don't

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know this is kinda resurrecting an old thread, but I recently solved this problem and haven't found any solutions posted online, so here goes...

With the latest kernels rnodes is enabled by default, but this still doesn't work... Next step is to check the ownership of the /dev/dri files...
e.g. on my system, I get:

```
$ ls -l /dev/dri
total 0
crw-rw---- 1 root video 226,   0 May 16 21:30 card0
crw-rw---- 1 root video 226,  64 May 16 21:30 controlD64
crw-rw---- 1 root video 226, 128 May 16 21:30 renderD128
```

Hinting I either need to be root user or a member of the "video" group to access the device...

Add the relevant user (i.e. the one you want to run the opencl program as) to the group:

```
usermod -a -G video <user>
```

Then relog and bingo no need to run as root anymore!

Comment: I've formatted my computer and lost the programs I was trying to run back then, and I haven't had the problem lately. However I'm accepting this answer because it's the only thing that has worked for someone and could probably help somebody else!

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert on beignet, but I know a thing or two about direct rendering, so this is what I could extract of reading some of the documentation.

beignet supports three modes:

1. connect directly to the device with root (*this is what you are doing*)
2. use dri2 to connect via the X server as a normal user
3. use the device directly over a direct render node as a normal user

**Before going any further**, you need to check if direct rendering is enabled in your video card driver and in the environment you're running your scripts on. This is done with the following command in the same terminal you're running your scripts:

```
glxinfo | grep render
```

It should output something like `Direct rendering: yes`, which is great. The glxinfo gives you all sort of other info that could be useful on helping find the source of your problem, so be sure to *update your question* with the complete output of the command (without the `| grep direct` part).

**Method 2** is the easiest method of using direct rendering, but requires the environment that is running the script to have a `DISPLAY` variable setting. If you're running it on a terminal emulator (like the Terminal app in Mint) it should be already set. You can check this by entering the following command:

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

it should print `:0` or something like that. If it doesn't show anything, then your script doesn't know which screen (or video card) to render to. This could happen if you're working on a remote machine via SSH, or using the terminal screen directly without a desktop environment. You can of course set this variable with this command:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

You just have to be sure that's the correct display to render to (the one running your X server), you can check in the output of glxinfo.

**Method 3** requires that your video card supports KVM (which apparently it does) and to enable rendering nodes. This is done when the system is booting up, so you need to modify your boot loader parameters to enable it. If you're booting using GRUB2, this is fairly simple (but, you know, back up any important thing in case anything goes wrong):

**As root**, you must edit the file `/etc/defaults/grub` and look for the following line (the … is because it can contain more parameters than just those two):

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash …"
```

Then, you must add the parameter that enables the rendering nodes at the end of that variable:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash … drm.rnodes=1"
```

After that, you save the file and execute the following command as root:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then reboot the computer, and your scripts should run as a normal user.

**UPDATE:** About the NVIDIA error that you're getting running as root, could it be possible that your laptop (because it's a laptop, right?) has hybrid graphic cards? if so, then you should be running OpenCL on the right card. Please update your question with the output of the following command:

```
lspci | grep -i vga
```

That should tell us exactly what hardware are you dealing with.

Comment: Thanks, I updated with the outputs you requested. However, I modified the grub file, but the programs will still only work properly on GPU when ran as root.

Comment: I should ask, do you get different outputs for the command `clinfo` if you run it with and without sudo?

Comment: Yes, without sudo I get the same error than when running my programs without sudo. Must run it with sudo to get the info.

Comment: I'm sorry but I think I'll let someone else take the case from now, I have a couple of ideas of what it might be, but it would require for you to rebuild packages or download things that are not really intended for your hardware... 
Here's some information I got about a bug with the nvidia module that could cause some issues: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2261090
Here are a couple of steps you can follow to build an ICD in a user directory instead of root: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730044/install-openclamd-sdk-kit-on-linux-without-root-privilege/20962333#20962333

Comment: My prime suspect was that your pyopencl package was build outside of your user's privileges, but if `clinfo` is also failing then the culprit is probably your beignet's installation, but if you used the package manager to install it you wouldn't have to worry about it.